# How to use custom JsonSerializer conditionally via annotation

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have written  a custom **JsonSerializer** to convert BigDecimal to String. I want  to  invoke this serializer using **@JsonSerialize** annotation but conditionally i.e. if a particular boolean value is true only then this BigDecimal  to  String conversion should  be done else not.

I have a POJO which  has  a  BigDecimal **price** field. This POJO is sent  in response  to two rest  calls:

- expects price  field as number  value //so @JsonSerialize should
  not run
- expects price field as string value //so  @JsonSerialize
  should run

Can anyone suggest how can I achieve it?

Below is the  code  snippet  of custom serializer I have  written:

```
public class BigDecimalToStringSerializer extends JsonSerializer<BigDecimal> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(BigDecimal value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeString(value.toString());
    }

}
```

POJO file having price field:

```
JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Price{
    private BigDecimal price;
    public Price() {
    }
    @JsonSerialize(using = BigDecimalToStringSerializer.class)
    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }   
    public void setPrice(BigDecimal pric) {
        this.price  = price;
    }
}
```

Thanks a ton in advance !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only change is required in custom serializer class:

```
public class BigDecimalToStringSerializer extends JsonSerializer<BigDecimal> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(BigDecimal value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {
    if (pojo instanceof Price && ((Price) pojo).shouldConvertInString()) {
        gen.writeString(value.toString());
    } else {
        gen.writeNumber(value);
    }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a `PropertyFilter` for this. First, you need to define the filter on our entity, using the `@JsonFilter` annotation:

```
@JsonFilter("stringValueFilter")
public class Price {
  private BigDecimal price;
  public Price() {
  }

  public BigDecimal getPrice() {
     return price;
  }   
  public void setPrice(BigDecimal pric) {
     this.price  = price;
  }
}
```

This is your `PropertyFilter`

```
public interface PropertyFilter {
    void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider prov, PropertyWriter writer);

    void serializeAsElement(Object elementValue, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider prov, PropertyWriter writer) throws Exception;

    void depositSchemaProperty(PropertyWriter writer, JsonObjectFormatVisitor objectVisitor, SerializerProvider provider) throws JsonMappingException;

    @Deprecated 
    void depositSchemaProperty(PropertyWriter writer, ObjectNode propertiesNode, SerializerProvider provider) throws JsonMappingException;
}
```

First method requires an special implementation for your case:

```
public class StringValueFilter implements PropertyFilter {
    void serializeAsField(Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider prov, PropertyWriter writer) {
        if (pojo instanceof Price && isValueFieldNumber((Price) pojo)) {
            return; // skip this field
        }
        writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, prov);
    }

    private isValueFieldNumber(Price price) {
        return: //check your logic and return
     }

    void serializeAsElement(Object elementValue, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider prov, PropertyWriter writer) throws Exception {
        writer.serializeAsField(elementValue, jgen, prov);
    }

    void depositSchemaProperty(PropertyWriter writer, JsonObjectFormatVisitor objectVisitor, SerializerProvider provider) throws JsonMappingException {
        writer.depositSchemaProperty(objectVisitor);
    }

    @Deprecated 
    void depositSchemaProperty(PropertyWriter writer, ObjectNode propertiesNode, SerializerProvider provider) throws JsonMappingException {
        writer.depositSchemaProperty(propertiesNode, provider);
    }
}
```

This filter contains the actual logic deciding if the `price` field is going to be serialized or not, based on its value.

Next, you need to hook this filter into the `ObjectMapper`:

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
final FilterProvider filterProvider = new SimpleFilterProvider()
        .addFilter("stringValueFilter", new StringValueFilter());
mapper.setFilters(filterProvider);
```

Comment: In my java code, the price field is always BigDecimal. For one rest endpoint I want this price field to be sent as it is i.e. number value. For other endpoint,  I want it to be sent in String format.
Where can I specify this boolean flag to check when to convert into String and when do nothing?

Comment: Just to add, Price class has other fields(Integers, BigDecimal, String etc) as well. So, how can I specify that only single field is serialized as String? And where is the logic to write the BigDecimal value as String?

Answer (score 3):

## 1.Place @JsonFilter on you Price class:

```
@JsonFilter("myFilter")
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Price {
    private BigDecimal price;
    public Price() {}
    @JsonSerialize(using = BigDecimalToStringSerializer.class)
    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(BigDecimal pric) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

### 2.Define CustomFilter logic

> Check if field is "price" :
>   if not, serialize normally and return
>   if so, check your boolean field to see if you sould serialize or not

```
    public class CustomFilter extends SimpleBeanPropertyFilter {
    @Override
    public void serializeAsField
        (Object pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider, PropertyWriter writer)
    throws Exception {
        if (include(writer)) {
            if (!writer.getName().equals("price")) {
                writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
                return;
            }
            Boolean toSerializeOrNot = ((MyDtoWithFilter) pojo).getYourCoditionalField();
            if (toSerializeOrNot) {
                writer.serializeAsField(pojo, jgen, provider);
            }
        } else if (!jgen.canOmitFields()) { 
            writer.serializeAsOmittedField(pojo, jgen, provider);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean include(BeanPropertyWriter writer) {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean include(PropertyWriter writer) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

## More Information

https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-serialize-field-custom-criteria

Comment: In my java code, the price field is always BigDecimal. For one rest endpoint I want this price field to be sent as it is i.e. number value. For other endpoint,  I want it to be sent in String format.
Where can I specify this boolean flag to check when to convert into String and when do nothing?

Comment: toSerializeOrNot = ((MyDtoWithFilter) pojo).getYourCoditionalField(); in this line you check your boolean flag within  Price class. note that your flag should be in the Price class and based on that you could decide to serialize it to string or do nothing

Comment: Just to add, Price class has other fields(Integers, BigDecimal, String etc) as well. So, how can I specify that only single field is serialized as String? And where is the logic to write the BigDecimal value as String?

Comment: see this code is trying to condition on your price field in the Price class which you annotate it with @JsonSerialize(using = BigDecimalToStringSerializer.class) , it means by default you want it to be serialized to string. then what we do is that we condition on another field e.g. ((MyDtoWithFilter) pojo).getYourCoditionalField() to check if it is alowed to use BigDecimalToStringSerializer for stringifying or not and leave other fields as is

Comment: see this code is trying to condition on your price field in the Price class which you annotate it with @JsonSerialize(using = BigDecimalToStringSerializer.class) , it means by default you want it to be serialized to string. then what we do is that we condition on another field e.g. ((MyDtoWithFilter) pojo).getYourCoditionalField() to check if it is alowed to use BigDecimalToStringSerializer for stringifying or not and leave other fields untouched.

Comment: Hi, what if I want other  way around? i.e by default  price fields should remain in number format while sending over network. But, in some cases it should  be  converted  into String?
Can you please help with that?

Comment: I realized  the  solution  you provided is  breaking my code.
My requirement is  simple:
1) if a flag value is true, do  not perfom custom serilization i.e. BigDecimal should  remain  as it is.
2) if  flag value  is  false, perform custom serialization i.e. convert BigDecimal to String. 
Can  you please  help  with this?

Comment: I have found  solution to my problem. Only thing which I had to do is: Put  a check in BigDecimalToStringSerilizer  class.